# Structured Streaming exception when using append output mode with watermark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Despite the fact that I'm using `withWatermark()`, I'm getting the following error message when I run my spark job:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;

From what I can see in the [programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking), this exactly matches the intended usage (and the example code). Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Relevant Code (Java 8, Spark 2.2.0):

```
StructType logSchema = new StructType()
        .add("timestamp", TimestampType)
        .add("key", IntegerType)
        .add("val", IntegerType);

Dataset<Row> kafka = spark
        .readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
        .option("subscribe", topics)
        .load();

Dataset<Row> parsed = kafka
        .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), logSchema).alias("parsed_value"))
        .select("parsed_value.*");

Dataset<Row> tenSecondCounts = parsed
        .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")
        .groupBy(
            parsed.col("key"),
            window(parsed.col("timestamp"), "1 day"))
        .count();

StreamingQuery query = tenSecondCounts
        .writeStream()
        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
        .outputMode("append")
        .format("console")
        .option("truncate", false)
        .start();
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is in `parsed.col`. Replacing it with `col` will fix the issue. I would suggest always using `col` function instead of `Dataset.col`.

`Dataset.col` returns `resolved column` while `col` returns `unresolved column`.

`parsed.withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")` will create a new Dataset with new columns with the same names. The watermark information is attached the `timestamp` column in the new Dataset, not `parsed.col("timestamp")`, so the columns in `groupBy` don't have watermark.

When you use unresolved columns, Spark will figure out the correct columns for you.

Comment: I am facing same issue , any clue what is wrong here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428367/analysisexception-append-output-mode-not-supported-when-there-are-streaming-agg